# Converting an int to a double by multiplying by 1.0 or adding 1d?

Tags: java, int, double, literals

As far as I know, to convert an integer to a double one can multiply the former by "1.0". It's apparently also possible to add "1d" (the double literal) to it. What, then, is the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show in code what exactly you mean. "Adding `1d`" is rather ambiguous.

Comment: `10 * 1.0d == 10.0` while `10 + 1d = 11.0`

Comment: Do you mean "add 'd'" to it, e.g. `42` becomes `42d`?  Adding `1d` would change it to `43.0`.

Comment: Those two operations are not the same. `x * 1.0 != x + 1.0`. 1d is just another way of writing 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you mean "add the `d` to the end of the numeral"...then there's no difference.  In Java, by default, all [floating-point literals are `double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2).

So these two literals are the same thing:

```
41.32
41.32d
```

If you were to add `f` instead of `d`, then one would be a `float` instead of a `double`.

You can change an `int` to a `double` in this way, too:

```
113
113d
```

If you're multiplying an `int` with a `double` to get a `double`, then the `int` [is being promoted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to a `double` so that the floating-point arithmetic can take place.

From the JLS:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'd' is like an explicit cast to a double, multiplying will also convert to double cause

> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double
>   before the operation is carried out.

and 1.0 is a double, so multiplying an int by *1.0*, would give a result of type double, but would also convert the other operand to double